# Zero watchers in directive if one-time binding is used in angular 1.3+

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made a `user-name` directive for this question

```
.directive('userName', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      user: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><span ng-bind="user.username"></span> <a ng-if="user.active">Add</a></div>',
  };
});
```

It is important that the directive uses a **minimal number of watches** when I use one-time binding af the user attribute (`<user-name user="::user"></user-name>`).

I have a number of questions. I have created **[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NlSu3VMVSIv8SdcfrRTv?p=preview)** to test my directive.

1. Why is there watchers in the *one-time-binding* case even though `user` will not update?
2. Can I get down to zero watchers in this directive when using one-time binding?
3. I have read in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that I need a $watch in a link function to update the DOM - this doesn't seem to be the case for me. When is $watch necessary in the link function?

Comment: 1,2. because `user` is undefined, unless you write $scope.user = "..." directly and synchronously in controller. you have created the whole new scope by using scope in directive, one more watcher inside new scope, does not matter much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getWatchers` function doesn't provide meaningful feedback on watchers (summing up the watchers from scopes doesn't make much sense also). You can try `$$postDigest` instead to monitor this kind of things.

Anyway, logging the scope from the directive after it was linked [will give better feedback instantly](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ja9pYvydsmvkRCBMvFms?p=preview).

As it shows, there are three watchers:

```
{isolateScope: Array[2], scope: Array[1]}
```

Two of them are `user.username` and `user.active`:

```
<div><span ng-bind="user.username"></span> <a ng-if="user.active">Add</a></div>
```

And the last one is `{{$index}}`:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users" id="user_a_{{$index}}">
```

Make them all one-time, and there should be zero.

> When is $watch necessary in the link function?

Exactly as it was said, when something in the DOM that doesn't have data binding has to be updated when watched scope property is updated.

$watch gives a good amount of control when compared to bindings, e.g. the recipe for one-time watcher is

```
  var unwatch = scope.$watch('oneTime', function (newVal, oldVal) {
     unwatch();
     ...
  });
```

And it can be changed to something like 'stop watching as soon as the variable is defined'.

It can also be used for watching the stuff outside the scope

```
scope.$watch(function () { return globalVar }, function () { scope.scopeVar = ... });
```

Comment: Thanks! So the one-time binding on the `user` attribute, can't be propagated down to the bindings inside the directive automatically? I would like the directive to be able to handle both two-way and one-time. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, these are two different bindings on two different scopes (the isolated one belongs to user-name and another one belongs to ng-repeat) . You are free to tailor the bindings as you wish for the sake of performance. I've updated the answer with one-time watcher.