# How to verify angular JS one time binding performance gain?

Tags: angularjs, performance

I want to remove watchers from my Angular JS application. To do that, I use the `::` keyword to apply one-time binding instead of watchers.

When I want to verify it using Angular Batarang or just plain `scope.$$watchers` (I think it works in the same way), I see that they still count as watchers.

Why are they appearing on the watchers list? What did I miss?

Comment: Normally `::` works exactly as advertised. Please, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here's an example of how watcher count can be (mis)interpreted http://stackoverflow.com/a/32508180/3731501.

Comment: @estus, I'm looking for a method that will calculate the real number of watchers (without the one-time binded ones).

Comment: One-time watchers are one-time, the name says it. They are removed from watcher list after they are triggered. See the example above. This is the way they are calculated, there's no need to verify Angular's work, unless there was an error from your side. Again, MCVE would help.

Comment: @estus, I don't need to verify AngularJS work - I need to know how much two binded watchers I have. Your example does not contain the code I need to do it. You can enhance your own MCVE to solve the discussed issue.

Comment: Your question is about *your* issue, isn't it? Yes, you can calculate them with Batarang or $$watchers, and yes, both should give the correct numbers. If you've done one-time bindings correctly.

Comment: That's exactly my issue, $$watchers or Batarang (that uses $$watchers) does not calculate it correctly as it does not remove one binded expressions from this list and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I think the $watcher is still attached to the value due to the nature of angular binding. But the single binded values won't be reevaluated every $digest cycle. So there is performance improvement using single-bind. See great documentation : [one time binding](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html)

Comment: I know that, I'm looking for a way to verify that it works.